# read text file which has been encoded with UCS-2 little Endian using Go

Tags: go, utf-8, ucs2

I have a Go program to read a text file similar to the code below:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("test.txt")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed opening file: %s", err)
    }

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)
    var txtlines []string

    for scanner.Scan() {
        txtlines = append(txtlines, scanner.Text())
    }

    file.Close()
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/cnDOEFaT0lr

The code works fine for all the text files except the files which have been encoded with UCS-2 little endian. How can I convert the file to UFT8 format to read it?

Answer (score 2):

> I have a Go program to read a text file. How can I convert the [UCS-2 little endian] file to UFT-8 format to read it?

---

> [Unicode](https://home.unicode.org/)
>
> [FAQ: UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 & BOM](https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html)
>
> Q: [What is the difference between UCS-2 and UTF-16?](https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-11)
>
> A: UCS-2 is obsolete terminology which refers to a Unicode
>   implementation up to Unicode 1.1, before surrogate code points and
>   UTF-16 were added to Version 2.0 of the standard. This term should now
>   be avoided.
>
> UCS-2 does not describe a data format distinct from UTF-16, because
>   both use exactly the same 16-bit code unit representations. However,
>   UCS-2 does not interpret surrogate code points, and thus cannot be
>   used to conformantly represent supplementary characters.
>
> Sometimes in the past an implementation has been labeled "UCS-2" to
>   indicate that it does not support supplementary characters and doesn't
>   interpret pairs of surrogate code points as characters. Such an
>   implementation would not handle processing of character properties,
>   code point boundaries, collation, etc. for supplementary characters.

UCS-2 is a proper subset of UTF-16.

---

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "golang.org/x/text/encoding/unicode"
)

func main() {
    // "Language Learning and Teaching" written in 16 or more languages: UCS-2
    // http://www.humancomp.org/unichtm/unilang.htm
    f, err := os.Open("unilang.htm")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    dec := unicode.UTF16(unicode.LittleEndian, unicode.IgnoreBOM).NewDecoder()
    scn := bufio.NewScanner(dec.Reader(f))
    for scn.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scn.Text())
    }
    if err := scn.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/3VombFxUNb1

Comment: The above code work fine for me. Thanks for the response. Now using the same code I am not able to read files "encode in UTF-8 withoutBOM". Is there a way to find the encode of the file? so that I can this logic only for UCS-2 encoded file?